# Android: AlarmManager inside a custom Object?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i have an ArrayList of custom objects which each contain the following 3 variables:

```
 private boolean mReminderActivated;
 private int mReminderHour;
 private int mReminderMinutes;
```

I am trying to set an Alarm from inside that Object, but i cant call getSystemService from inside the Object. Can i only set up Alarms in Activities and Fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not instantiate AlarmManager. You ask Android for the existing instance as follows:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

where `context` is you current Android context, typically your Activity.

See https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html for reference.

Update - based on the comments below, it seems your problem is how to get the context for use within your object.  Here is one suggestion:

Pass the context to your custom class in the constructor.  So your class will look something like this (I'm calling it Foo as you did not provide a name). I've provided a `setAlarm()` method that shows how you would get the AlarmManager.

```
class Foo {

    private boolean mReminderActivated;
    private int mReminderHour;
    private int mReminderMinutes;

        public Foo(Context context, boolean mReminderActivated, int mReminderHour, int mReminderMinutes) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mReminderActivated = mReminderActivated;
            this.mReminderHour = mReminderHour;
            this.mReminderMinutes = mReminderMinutes;
        }

        public void setAlarm() {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        }

        ...
    }
```

Then, in your activity, you would create your Foo object as follows:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(this, ....
```

Comment: Right, i asked the question wrongly. I tried that before, but i cant get the activity via getActivity(). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you calling getActivity() within your custom object?

Comment: I try to. Is that not possible? I am still newbie. So far i had no problem learning to add new features but i am stuck at adding alarms.

Comment: See my edit above.  I've provided a possible way to do this.

Comment: Hey, i tried this but my App freezes as soon as i try to save the Context in the Objects variable.